# Highlight integer points in RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, regions

Is there any way to mark integer points after plotting region in *Mathematica*?
For example, if I:

```
RegionPlot[x >= 4 y && x <= 4 y + 3 , {x, 0, 63}, {y, 0, 15}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

then it highlights the region but I want to see Y value corresponding to integer X value.  Can I do it with *Mathematica*?

Comment: I added a graphic to your post to help illustrate.  Could you describe in more detail what you expect to see, please?

Comment: Like in above image I want to mark (x,y) where both x and y are integers.

Answer (score 9):

Use the inequality to sow all integer coordinates that are inside the boundary of the region when iterating through all integer pairs of the full range:

```
pts = First@Last@Reap@Do[If[x >= 4 y && x <= 4 y + 3, Sow@{x, y}], {x, 0, 63}, {y, 0, 15}]
RegionPlot[x >= 4 y && x <= 4 y + 3, {x, 0, 63}, {y, 0, 15}, Epilog -> {Red, Point@pts}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Amazing..Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 8):

Another way to *generate* all the points is by using [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html):

```
points = {x, y} /. 
 List@ToRules@
   Reduce[x >= 4 y && x <= 4 y + 3 && 0 < x < 63 && 0 < y < 15, {x, y}, Integers]
```

If you give bounds (and thus constrain the possible solutions to a finite set), `Reduce` will typically list all solutions.

Then just plot them with `Point` or `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[points]
```

Show them together with the `RegionPlot`:

```
Show[ListPlot[points], RegionPlot[...]]
```

---

Thanks to Mr.Wizard to pointing me to the following relevant note in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DiophantineReduce.html#226945663):

> *Mathematica* enumerates the solutions explicitly only if the number of integer solutions of the system does not exceed the maximum of the $p^{\text{th}}$ power of the value of the [system option](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SystemOptions.html) `DiscreteSolutionBound`, where $p$ is the dimension of the solution lattice of the equations, and the second element of the value of the system option `ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints`.

Comment: Might want to mention `ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints`. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the pointer.  I didn't know about this option.

Comment: I changed your documentation link to an anchor I thought was more appropriate.  If you disagree change it back, or perhaps add a second one.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree, but I am usually too lazy to dig out the precise anchor (if it is not linked to and I can't just copy the link).  Is there an easier way than using the dev tools of the browser or looking at the web page source?

Comment: There's a [Meta post about that.](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/476/121)  I still use View Selection Source myself; it really doesn't take long.  If your browser only lets you view the source of the entire page I can see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can generate just the points you want and then plot them :

```
data = DeleteCases[Flatten[Outer[Boole[4 #2 <= #1 <= 4 #2 + 3] {#1, #2} &, 
    Range[0, 63], Range[0, 15]], 1], {0, 0}];

Show[RegionPlot[x >= 4 y && x <= 4 y + 3, {x, 0, 63}, {y, 0, 15}],  ListPlot[data]]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

Another, using smart and fast functions like `Array` and `Tuples`, thus a bit more recommended way  :

```
RegionPlot[ x >= 4 y && x <= 4 y + 3, {x, 0, 63}, {y, 0, 15}, Epilog -> { 
            Red, PointSize[0.005], 
            Point[ Join @@ Tuples /@ Array[ {Range[4 #, 4 # + 3], {#}} &, {16}, 0]]}, 
            AspectRatio -> 15/63 ]
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, you can just do `AspectRatio -> Automatic`...

Comment: @RahulNarain That's all ?

Comment: I mean, instead of manually specifying 15/63.